# Picture caption format

Tags: floats

i have a problem with my picture captions. I have two pictures side by side

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.479\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Auswertung/sanyo_eol_e2_lite.png}
        \caption{Klassifizierung des reduzierten Sanyo Datensatzes mit synthetisch generierten Trainingsdaten und $\upvarepsilon = 2$.}
        \label{fig:a_san_e2}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.479\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Auswertung/sanyo_eol_e3_full.png}
        \caption{Klassifizierung des vollständigen Sanyo Datensatzes mit synthetisch generierten Trainingsdaten und $\upvarepsilon = 3$.}
        \label{fig:a_san_full}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

But this causes this ugly caption format:
[image]

i'd like to have the text continued directly under "Abbildung" with a little indent instead of starting after the ":"
How can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can load the `caption` package and add `\captionsetup{format=plain}` (what you have is the `hang` format).

Comment: This works, thanks. Can you write this as answer, so i can mark it as solution?

Comment: I've just done it, adding the small indent, and a suggestion to replace the minipages with floatrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a small indent from the second line of the caption, you can define an`indent`  caption format with the `caption` package.

I also advise to load the `floatrow` package for figures in a row. It uses different syntax for each figure; in the form `\ffigbox{\caption ... \label ...}{\includegraphics{...}}`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{indent}{\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 #1#2 #3}
 \usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering\captionsetup{format=indent, labelfont=bf}
    \floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad}
    \begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox{\caption{Klassifizierung des reduzierten Sanyo Datensatzes mit synthetisch generierten Trainingsdaten und $\upvarepsilon = 2$.} \label{fig:a_san_e2}}%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Auswertung/sanyo_eol_e2_lite.png}}

    \ffigbox{\caption{Klassifizierung des vollständigen Sanyo Datensatzes mit synthetisch generierten Trainingsdaten und $\upvarepsilon = 3$.}\label{fig:a_san_full}}%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Auswertung/sanyo_eol_e3_full.png}}
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]